# Why I can't be able to catch Exceptions under Object class reference when Object class is the super class for all?

Tags: java, exception

From my research on google, most sites say that "Throwable" is the ultimate superclass for Exceptions. I accept it, but even when Throwable is a sub-class of Object class why I can't able to store exceptions under Object class?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EZsz.jpg

Comment: That's a bit like asking *why can't I call `object.put("a", "A")` even if `Object` is ultimately a superclass of `Map`*... Some behavior is designed with a select parent class or interface, and `Throwable` is the ancestor of all exceptions, as you read.

Comment: Of course you can *"store exceptions under Object class"*, `Object o = new RuntimeException();` is perfectly legal. You cannot `catch` an `Object` though, because not every `Object` can be thrown.

Comment: @ernest_k if `java.util.Map` is an interface, how can it be a subclass of `Object`?

Comment: @Abra It makes little difference; but you're right, I should have said *supertype* instead of "superclass", for Map's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't throw an arbitrary object because the language says you can't: [JLS 14.18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18)

You can't catch an arbitrary object because the language says you can't: [JLS 14.20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-CatchFormalParameter)

The intent is to restrict exception objects to a particular hierarchy.